# Support as a Proportion in Apriori

Tags: self-study

[image]

I'm asked to find association rules with support >= 0.3 and confidence >= 0.6.  For support as a percentage, we need to divide the support of the candidate itemset by the the total number of records at each k-item stage of the algorithm?

ie.,

for 1 item itemsets:
supp({1}) = 3/8
supp({2}) = 5/8
supp({3}) = 5/8

all pass the threshold, so, for 2 item itemsets:
supp({1,2}) = 2/8
supp({2,3}) = 2/8
supp({1,3}) = 3/8

Giving 1 -> 3 and 3 -> 1 as possible association rules? (need to check confidence).

Comment: Yes, filler text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the support as a percentage is called the **relative support.**

It is calculated as the number of transactions containing the itemset divided by the total number of transactions.